# Is there a way to not print a newline in python?

Tags: python

I want to make a pyramid but there is a new line after every for loop.
This is worked example 12.01 in the CAIE A-Level Textbook.

```
maxnumber = 2
numberofspaces = 0
numberofsymbols = 1
# Set values
symbol = input("Enter a symbol.\n")
while maxnumber % 2 == 0:
    maxnumber = int(input("Enter the number of symbols you want in the base.\n"))
numberofspaces = int((maxnumber - 1) / 2)
while numberofsymbols <= maxnumber:
    for space in range(numberofspaces):
        print(" ")
    for i in range(numberofsymbols):
        print(symbol)
    print("\n")
    numberofsymbols += 2
    numberofspaces -= 1
```

Expected results-

```
  $
 $$$
$$$$$
```

Actual results-

```
$



$
$
$


$
$
$
$
$
```

Comment: Have you considered using `'{:^5}'.format('$')`?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want new line, simply add new argument `end=''`

```
print(symbol,end='')
```